# Pass equations into shaders to define graphics - HLSL or other shaders

Tags: shaders, hlsl, geometry-shader, vertex-shader, surface-shader

Is it possible with HLSL (or other popular shader languages) to pass instead of an image, an equation that would define the pixel color / position output by the shader? This would allow for more dynamic drawing of smooth shapes that could be sampled with infinite detail. They would also by able to change and morph in real time.

Not sure how this is possible without passing a string with the eq to the shader and having it parse it. Seems like that might lose all the performance gained by putting it onto the GPU.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to ask is "How to render {description of dynamic shapes you have in mind} with the GPU?" The simple answer to your question is "no" you can't just upload a new equation (though you could compile your equation as a shader and upload that, or encode the parameters of your equation into uniforms/texture data and evaluate them in an uber-shader that models all equations in a family). But there may be other ways that similarly achieve what you want, albeit through different means.

Comment: Shader itself is your "equation". Switch between different shaders to get what you need. If you need to switch "mid-way" - use an uber-shader (described in the answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply define enumeration values at the top of your shader and use a switch statement to select the equation you wish to use, then upload the corresponding integer value you wish to use to select the equation from the switch statement?

I’m not a great graphics programmer, but i believe this technique is called an [uber shader](https://community.khronos.org/t/creating-a-production-quality-shader-uber/68508)

If you require more than just one switch statement, you could use [bit packing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/hlsl-pack-4-values-into-32-bit-float) to store several values in one float, and then unpack them in the shader.

Comment: This is not extensible enough for my purposes, though with a lot of options I suppose it'd be helpful. I would like to be able to pass the shader an equation defining a surface, which HLSL could then shade and color. The vertex shader would use 2 triangles to fill the screen (or the area the object will contain) and the pixel shader will either output a pixel or nothing for where the surface is defined

Comment: @alaokastrail It sounds like you're describing [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) style effects, which are generally accomplished by taking the equation you want to render and compiling it as a shader.

Comment: @alaokastrail what type of equation for a surface do you intend to pass? Polynomial equations are simple to handle, by simply passing the coefficients in as vectors. If you intend to pass user-defined equations, that is a horse of a different color. You will need to recompile the shader if you intend to explicitly pass equations in, as well as figure out a way to convert raw binary into characters and then parse said equations with some sort of evaluation technique like oldschool calculators.